# Spring Data MongoDB - Views, @CompoundIndex and annotation inheritance

Tags: spring, inheritance, view, annotations, spring-data-mongodb

I'm running into an issue trying to leverage inheritance in combination with MongoDB views and `@CompoundIndex`.  Say I have a collection `items` and a view of that collection called `itemsView`.  I'm representing these entities in my models like so:

```
@Document(collection = "items")
@CompoundIndex(name = "view_active_available" def = "{active: 1, quantity: 1}")
public class Item {
    // Adding index on collection that view definition will leverage
}
```

Then, for the view I want to extend the `Item` class so that I can leverage its members, getters/setters, etc. when reading from the view, as such:

```
@Document(collection = "itemsView")
public class ItemAvailable extends Item {
     // Now I can read from the view but treat them as `Item` instances
}
```

Knowing that it's not possible to create indexes on views I checked the Spring Data MongoDB source for the `@CompoundIndex` annotation and found:

```
/**
 * Mark a class to use compound indexes.
 * ...
 */
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE })
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CompoundIndex {
    ...
}
```

Perfect, `@CompoundIndex` is not `@Inherited` so this should work fine, I thought.  So I built and fired up my app and sadly ran into this:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'itemsView': Invocation of init method failed;
>   nested exception is org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Command failed with error 166: 'Cannot create indexes on a view'

So, Spring is trying to create the index on the view after all.

What I'm trying to accomplish seems like it must be a common design challenge when working with views (and their entities, which are just a "normal" non-view entities after all).

**Why is the non-inherited `@CompoundIndex` annotation getting applied to the subclass?**

---

Update: After doing extensive debugging I believe this may be a bug in Spring Data MongoDB.  `MongoPersistentEntintyIndexResolver` has a `potentiallyCreateCompoundIndexDefinitions` method which explicitly checks for the presence of `@CompoundIndexes` and `@CompoundIndex` on the class (entity) in question.  It does so by calling Spring Data's `BasicPersistentEntity.findAnnotation` method.  That method traverses up the inheritance chain looking for the specified annotation, returning it if it's found *regardless of where in the class hierarchy it was found*.  There's no checking in `potentiallyCreateCompoundIndexDefinitions` (or anywhere else) to see if the annotation was found on a superclass and if so whether or not the `@Inherited` annotation was present.

Comment: Have to wonder why this got downvoted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Data MongoDB's [MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/1.10.12.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/index/MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.html) calls an internal private method `potentiallyCreateCompoundIndexDefinitions`, passing in the [BasicPersistentEntity](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mapping/model/BasicPersistentEntity.html#findAnnotation-java.lang.Class-) it's examining.  That method in turn calls the entity's [findAnnotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mapping/model/BasicPersistentEntity.html#findAnnotation-java.lang.Class-) method which finally defers to [AnnotatedElementUtils.findMergedAnnotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/AnnotatedElementUtils.html#findMergedAnnotation-java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedElement-java.lang.Class-).

From the docs for that class:

> Support for @Inherited
>
> Methods following get semantics will honor the contract of Java's @Inherited annotation except that locally declared annotations (including custom composed annotations) will be favored over inherited annotations. In contrast, methods following find semantics will completely ignore the presence of @Inherited since the find search algorithm manually traverses type and method hierarchies and thereby implicitly supports annotation inheritance without a need for @Inherited.

So the behavior I'm experiencing is correct per this documentation.  However I believe this is a bug with Spring Data MongoDB - to properly respect `@Inherited` it needs to call one of the `get` annotation methods instead of the `find` method in order prevent inheritance of non-`@Inherited` annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Framework uses its own logic while looking for annotations and by default inspects implemented interface and super-class types. `@Inherited` doesn't change anything.

Anyway, as I remember when I ran in a similar issue, there's no way of avoiding inheriting compound indexes.

Comment: This is incorrect.  See docs here:  https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/AnnotatedElementUtils.html#findMergedAnnotation-java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedElement-java.lang.Class-

Comment: The sense of my answer, maybe not clearly, is that the *absence* of `@Inherited` doesn't imply that annotation has not to be searched in the hierarchies. And that's because of the _find_ logic.